# Merge a broken line when i find a specific character in Python

Tags: python

Could anyone help me?i have got a file to read like this:

```
> 200701130720 METAR LIMF 130720Z VRB01KT CAVOK 02/M01 Q1025= 
> 200701130820 METAR LIMF 130820Z VRB03KT 1000 R36/P1500N BCFG FEW003
> 02/M01
>                                                                  Q1026=
```

I want to re_write the file printing line by line but going in a new line when i find equal (equal means the end of the line) and finally cancel equal!Thank you

Comment: Looks like you have [quoted-printable encoded data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) then. Perhaps the [`quopri` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/quopri.html) can help here?

Comment: Other than that, have you tried anything yourself yet? You can use a list to 'collect' lines you have read so far that end with a `=` and only write a line to the new file when you found one without `=` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that could help:

```
import string

a = """
200701130720 METAR LIMF 130720Z VRB01KT CAVOK 02/M01 Q1025= 
200701130820 METAR LIMF 130820Z VRB03KT 1000 R36/P1500N BCFG FEW003
02/M01
                                                                 Q1026=
"""

def main():
    output = string.replace(a,"=", "")
    output = string.replace(output,"  ", "")
    output = string.replace(output,"\n", "")
    print output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am using `replace()` function to replace `"=", "  ", "\n"` with `""`. So that it prints everything in the same line.

output:

```
200701130720 METAR LIMF 130720Z VRB01KT CAVOK 02/M01 Q1025 200701130820 METAR LIMF 130820Z VRB03KT 1000 R36/P1500N BCFG FEW00302/M01 Q1026
```